# creating text files from sqlite data

Tags: sqlite, text

I have started to use (or, try to use) sqlite for a simple catalog. What I want to do is be able to take out the information for each catalogued item from the sqlite, and export it into a text file. 
e.g.

Title1, Genre1, Author1

Title2, Genre2, Author2

Title3, Genre3, Author3

I don't want these to be in columns, just a single line. Also, is there a way to use multiple different separators?

This seems like it should be relatively easy to do, but I am totally new to this and can't figure it out.

Comment: i wasn't as clear as i meant to be. i was wondering if it was possible to get the title printed within a tag (like, '''Title1''' or <b>Title1</b>) separated with a comma, and then have the Genre and Author separated with a / . So, each line would look like:

<b>Title</b>, Genre / Author

Answer (score 5):

> `sqlite -list -separator ', ' db.db 'select * from thetable'`

should do.

Answer (score 0):

Like @hacker said, you can use `sqlite -list` when you need to specify the delimiter character.  You can also use simple output such as `sqlite -csv` if you don't need to be terribly specific.

You probably want to refer to [the SQLite command line documentation](http://sqlite.org/sqlite.html) for more information about generating textual output from an interactive SQLite command, or you could [`man sqlite`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/sqlite31.html) too, although it's similar information.